# Square-connect Business Name(Nick Name) retrieval Issue

Tags: square-connect, square

I am using squareup API version1 to get locations. I am getting locations via API but name and business name value not begin properly returned. I am not able to get same nickname via api. For example: if I have businessName (Abc) in UI I am getting (XYZ) via API I am using following end point 
/v1/me/locations

Comment: it's probably a bad idea to share phone number's and email address of other people anywhere in the internet

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right authorization credentials? It can be easy to confuse the tokens with different merchants and pull the locations for a different business

Comment: thanks for reply.I got proper value from location_details in json response